How to move a project from Microsoft Team Foundation System to GIT with GIT-TFS?
My actual TFS environment is structured as follows:
+DefaultCollection
    +Collection1
    +Collection2
    +Collection3
        +Prod
            +Project1
            +Project2
        +Test
            +Project4

following what in
https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code/importing-a-team-foundation-version-control-repository
related to "migrating with git-tfs"
it is not clear to me how I can migrate Project2 to GIT, I tried several different ways, but not able until now to have a successful migration of a project from TFS to GIT including all history
(also older than 180 days).
I've been able to clone to local (my local disk) the whole environment (even if with some error while going) using the command
    MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 git tfs clone --branches=auto http://XXXX/DefaultCollection $/
which worked for some hour producing a local image of the whole DefaultCollection.
Also in this case, how can I push to the remote GIT only the Project2?
thank you for any help
Mauro
I tried all suggested git-tfs command I was able to find online, but I'm missing something or maybe what I want to get is not possible.

git is not capitalized, btw.

Regarding your TFS Project2 - does it remain at $Collection3/Prod/Project throughout its entire history in TFS? Or did you ever do any TFS branching or movements to other paths? If not, then that does make things simpler...

Hi Dai, each project can be considered containing its entire history in TFS.

Microsoft wrote an article about that: Import and migrate repositories from TFVC to Git

yes, I got this and it works, but it is limited to last 180 days history.

I also tried to follow this https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code/importing-a-team-foundation-version-control-repository but the instructions at "migrating with git-tfs" fails (to me) at step 6, where I should clone the project to a local folder to be after able to push it to the git repository.

If Project2 is slef contained git tfs clone --branches=none http://XXXX/DefaultCollection $/Collection3/Prod/Project2  should work.

Maybe git tfs list-remote-branches http://XXXX/DefaultCollection could help

Hi @Philippe, tried to follow your suggestion, but I get: TFS repository can not be root and must start with "$/."

@Philippe trying the git tfs lit-remote-branches gives me the "$/Collection3/Prod" as a result.
